# How to attach an AWS managed policy to a role in cloudformation and troposphere

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

In my troposphere code i basically want to create an sns topic and a lambda execution role to which i can attach a few managed policy from aws. But the issue is i cannot find a way to just reference the arn name of the managed policy. Below is my code but here i am copying and pasting the managed policy json document.

Is there a better way out ?

```
from troposphere import FindInMap, GetAtt, Join, Output, Template, Ref, ImportValue
from troposphere.sns import Topic
from troposphere.iam import Role, Policy


t = Template()

t.set_version("2010-09-09")

sns_topic = Topic(TopicName='IngestStateTopic', title='IngestStateTopic')

t.add_resource(sns_topic)

LambdaExecutionRole = t.add_resource(
    Role(
        "LambdaExecutionRole",
        Path="/",
        Policies=[
            Policy(PolicyName="CloudWatchLogsFullAccess",
                   PolicyDocument={
                       "Version":
                       "2012-10-17",
                       "Statement": [{
                           "Action": ["logs:*"],
                           "Effect": "Allow",
                           "Resource": "*"
                       }]
                   }),
            Policy(PolicyName="SnsReadOnlyAccess",
                   PolicyDocument={
                       "Version":
                       "2012-10-17",
                       "Statement": [{
                           "Effect":
                           "Allow",
                           "Action": ["sns:GetTopicAttributes", "sns:List*"],
                           "Resource":
                           "*"
                       }]
                   }),
            Policy(PolicyName="LambdaBasicExecutionRole-Test",
                   PolicyDocument={
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:498129003450:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:498129003450:log-group:/aws/lambda/lambda_layers_test:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
})
        ],
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument={
            "Version":
            "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [{
                "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
                }
            }]
        },
    ))

t.add_output(
    Output(
    "IngestServiceArn",
    Description="ARN of the sns topic",
    Value=Ref(sns_topic),
))

t.add_output(
    Output(
    "LambdaExcecutionRole",
    Description="ARN of the lambda plocy document",
    Value=GetAtt(LambdaExecutionRole, "Arn"),
))

with open('sns_lambda_role.yaml', 'w') as s:
    s.write(t.to_yaml())
```

And below is my cloud formation yaml file name:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Outputs:
  IngestServiceArn:
    Description: ARN of the sns topic
    Value: !Ref 'IngestStateTopic'
  LambdaExcecutionRole:
    Description: ARN of the lambda plocy document
    Value: !GetAtt 'LambdaExecutionRole.Arn'
Resources:
  IngestStateTopic:
    Properties:
      TopicName: IngestStateTopic
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - logs:*
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
            Version: '2012-10-17'
          PolicyName: CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
        - PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - sns:GetTopicAttributes
                  - sns:List*
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
            Version: '2012-10-17'
          PolicyName: SnsReadOnlyAccess
        - PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action: logs:CreateLogGroup
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:498129003450:*
              - Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Effect: Allow
                Resource:
                  - arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:498129003450:log-group:/aws/lambda/lambda_layers_test:*
            Version: '2012-10-17'
          PolicyName: LambdaBasicExecutionRole-Test
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by specifying a list of  `ManagedPolicyArns` for Role cloudformation resource, but not the `Policies` - [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html):

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties" : {
      "AssumeRolePolicyDocument" : Json,
      "ManagedPolicyArns" : [ String, ... ],
      "MaxSessionDuration" : Integer,
      "Path" : String,
      "PermissionsBoundary" : String,
      "Policies" : [ Policy, ... ],
      "RoleName" : String
    }
}
```

For ManagedPolicy CloudFormation has separate resource type - [AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-managedpolicy.html):

```
SampleManagedPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Sid: AllowAllUsersToListAccounts
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - iam:ListAccountAliases
              - iam:ListUsers
              - iam:GetAccountSummary
            Resource: "*
```

Examle:

```
RootRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterOne            
        - !Ref awsExampleManagedPolicyParameterTwo
```

So, if we are talking about the **tropopshere** - it also has separate class for ManagedPolicy:

```
class ManagedPolicy(AWSObject):
    resource_type = "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"

    props = {
        'Description': (basestring, False),
        'Groups': ([basestring], False),
        'ManagedPolicyName': (basestring, False),
        'Path': (iam_path, False),
        'PolicyDocument': (policytypes, True),
        'Roles': ([basestring], False),
        'Users': ([basestring], False),
    }
```

And you refer to it using `Ref` function.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [awacs](https://github.com/cloudtools/awacs) project which allows for policy definition.

Also, likely you need to just Ref() your policy to get the name of it.